# Correlation with heatmap between 2 columns with different dataset in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I would like to seek support pertaining to the correlation matrix for 2 different dataset and generating it to a heatmap.

Listed below is the sample data:

| Expression | PR | Metrics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Engagement | 0.33 | 0.70 |
| Excitement | 0.33 | 0.15 |
| Focus | 0.33 | 0.36 |
| Interest | 0.67 | 0.47 |
| Relaxation | 0.55 | 0.20 |
| Stress | 0.44 | 0.40 |

As these data are not imported from a csv file (Due to the need for modification in future), it is created via a df. And the values are converted to float using **astype(float)**

The way that I have created the df and converting the types are provided here.

```
data = {
    'Expression':['Engagement', 'Excitement', 'Focus','Interest','Relaxation','Stress'],
    'PR': ['0.33','0.33','0.33','0.67','0.55','0.44'],
    'Metrics': ['0.70','0.15','0.36','0.47','0.20','0.40']
    }

df['PR']=df['PR'].astype(float) #Converts object dtype to float
df['Emotiv Metrics']=df['Emotiv Metrics'].astype(float) #Converts object dtype to float
```

After which, if I were to use `df.corr()`, it will only provide the correlation result as shown:

```
                      PR        Metrics
PR              1.000000       -0.048189
Metrics        -0.048189        1.000000
```

However, what I would like to generate is a correlation matrix that shows the correlation between **EACH** expression from the PR and Metrics, as to what is provided in the snipped image, inclusive of the **Metrics** and **PR**.

[image]

How should I go about it in this case then?

Or if there's any error pertaining to the above code, please do point out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with transpose `DataFrame` with [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import seaborn as sb

df1 = df.set_index('Expression')[['PR','Metrics']]
df = df1.dot(df1.T).rename_axis(index='name1', columns='name2')
print (df)

name2       Engagement  Excitement   Focus  Interest  Relaxation  Stress
name1                                                                   
Engagement      0.5989      0.2139  0.3609    0.5501      0.3215  0.4252
Excitement      0.2139      0.1314  0.1629    0.2916      0.2115  0.2052
Focus           0.3609      0.1629  0.2385    0.3903      0.2535  0.2892
Interest        0.5501      0.2916  0.3903    0.6698      0.4625  0.4828
Relaxation      0.3215      0.2115  0.2535    0.4625      0.3425  0.3220
Stress          0.4252      0.2052  0.2892    0.4828      0.3220  0.3536

sb.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I would to query if it is possible to have the Axes being renamed?

Such that the title at y-axis is called either Metrics or PR, similar for the x-axis.

Comment: @Jun - Added `rename_axis(index='name1', columns='name2')`, change `name1` and `name2` like need.

Comment: @jazrael, May I check if the usage of Spearman Rank Correlation on the sample data provided is possible?

If yes, how would I go about it?